# Swift Package Manifest - What is the difference between library targets and target dependencies?

Tags: swift, dependencies, swift-package-manager, swift-package

In Package.swift, what is the difference between adding a target the array of targets within a library versus adding a target to the array of dependencies.

In this first example, 'Helpers' is added as a dependency to the 'MySwiftPackage' target.

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyTestPackage",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyTestPackage",
            targets: ["MyTestPackage"]),
        .library(
            name: "Helper",
            targets: ["Helper"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyTestPackage",
            dependencies: ["Helper"]), // <---- 'Helper' defined as dependency
        .target(
            name: "Helper",
            dependencies: []),
    ]
)
```

In this next example, 'Helper' is added as another target within the 'MySwiftPackage' library.

```
let package = Package(
        name: "MyTestPackage",
        products: [
            .library(
                name: "MyTestPackage",
                targets: ["MyTestPackage","Helper",]), // <-- 'Helper' defined in targets
            .library(
                name: "Helper",
                targets: ["Helper"]),
        ],
        dependencies: [
        ],
        targets: [
            .target(
                name: "MyTestPackage",
                dependencies: []),
            .target(
                name: "Helper",
                dependencies: []),
        ]
    )
```

From what I can tell, both options produce the same result: when I declare MySwiftPackage as a dependency inside of an Xcode project, I am able to import both the 'MySwiftPackage' module and the 'Helper' module.

Is there a significant difference between the two manifest files other than where 'Helper' is placed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Swift Package Manager Documentation](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/tree/main/Documentation#about-products)

```
A target may build either a library or an executable as its product.
A library contains a module that can be imported by other Swift code. 
...
```

A library is something that can be imported by other swift code.

The dependencies that your library relies on are defined in the

```swift
.target(name: "MyTestPackage", dependencies: ["Helper"])
```

The targets could be thought of as the modules, organized in folders.

When you define the `MyTestPackage`, you declare its dependencies `Helper` in the targets array of the package. If you didn't declare it there, code in `MyTestPackage` won't be able to import Helpers.

In the first example, the library `MyTestPackage`'s target includes helpers as a dependency of `MyTestPackage`, so you could delete the `Helper` library and should still be able to import both MyTestPackage and Helper in your project.

In the second example, you declare both `MyTestPackage` and `Helpers` as targets that make up the `MyTestPackage` library, so again you should be able to delete the `Helper` library and still import code from both modules.

If you were to delete both libraries from either example, you would not be able to import any code into your project